# What is the formula for the drag-down operation of Excel's range

Tags: excel-formula

What is the formula for the drop-down（or drag down） operation of Excel's range?

input 2,5,7,9 then drag down,show 11.5 13.8 16.1 18.4 .... step 2.3

input 5,10,20 then drag down,show 26.66667 34.166667 41.66667 .... step 7.5

input 1,2,3,5 then drag down,show 6 7.3 8.6 9.9 11.2 .... step 1.3

Comment: Interesting question.  Unfortunately [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db) microsoft support page doesn't answer it, but it does show us that this feature is quite wide-ranging.  I wasn't aware you could do this in Excel so +1 for at least highlighting it.

Comment: By 'drop down' do you mean 'drag down' or 'flash fill'?

Comment: yes, you are right. I am developing a jquery plugin similar to excel. I call it quicksheet temporarily

Comment: re you sure your 2, 5, 7 results are correct? I get 9.67, 12.167, 14.67, 17.167, ...

Comment: sorry, it's 2,5,7,9

Answer (score 2):

The step is given by the [`LINEST`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/linest-function-84d7d0d9-6e50-4101-977a-fa7abf772b6d) function which:

> The LINEST function calculates the statistics for a line by using the "least squares" method to calculate a straight line that best fits your data.

The 'step' from your examples is shown calculated here:

[image]

You might also check out the [`FORECAST`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/forecast-function-50ca49c9-7b40-4892-94e4-7ad38bbeda99) formula which will predict the series you see when you drag down. With your third example I added an index which is required for the regression calculation:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic!  but There is still one question left:  11.5 - 9 != 2.3 , 26.66667 - 20 != 7.5, 6-5!=1

Comment: You need to replicate the behaviour of the Forecast function then the different initial step is accounted for.